# While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

This error is what I get if I run the application on the server, but not locally. Why is this happening on the server and not locally???

```
List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

// establish domain context
PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// find your user
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, userName);

// if found - grab its groups
if (user != null)
{
//here happens the error on server.
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

Please help me.

stack trace:

```
   [PrincipalOperationException: While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred.]
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthZSet..ctor(Byte[] userSid, NetCred credentials, ContextOptions contextOptions, String flatUserAuthority, StoreCtx userStoreCtx, Object userCtxBase) +317263
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOfAZ(Principal p) +441
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroupsHelper() +78
   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups() +11
   IntegrationApp.App_Code.ActiveDir.GetGroups(String userName) in C:\Documents and Settings\mta\My Documents\IntegrationApp\IntegrationApp\App_Code\3-Tier\DAL\ActiveDir.cs:54
   IntegrationApp.App_Code._3_Tier.BAL.DatabaseBAL.BepaalDefaultNiveau2(String melder) in C:\Documents and Settings\mta\My Documents\IntegrationApp\IntegrationApp\App_Code\3-Tier\BAL\DatabaseBAL.cs:75
   IntegrationApp.Detailscherm.VulLijsten() in C:\Documents and Settings\mta\My Documents\IntegrationApp\IntegrationApp\Detailscherm.aspx.cs:89
   IntegrationApp.Detailscherm.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\mta\My Documents\IntegrationApp\IntegrationApp\Detailscherm.aspx.cs:30
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2428
```

Comment: please add more context. What kind of application, where is it failing, what error message did you get? Add some code.

Comment: what's the error message + stack trace?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found another solution to get access to the GROUPS:

```
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetGroups();
```

Comment: user.GetGroups() and user.GetAuthorizationGroups() is not really the same thing?

Comment: No they are not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162008/userprincipal-getgroups-vs-userprincipal-getauthorizationgroups

Comment: `GetGroups` did not result in an error like `GetAuthorizationGroups`, but did not return the complete list of groups that `GetAuthorizationGroups` did.

Answer (score 3):

Under what identity is your process running on the server? Most likely, that user does not have the correct rights to access your Active Directory.

Can you test if it works with this constructor of PrincipalContext?

```
PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MY.DOMAIN.HERE", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");
```

If that works, you probably want to create a dedicated domain user for your app to run under.

Answer (score 3):

I found that membership in the Windows Authorization Access Group is required to execute GetAuthorizationGroups.

See the following article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331951

Comment: Is this a good idee tho?
I mean to give elevated permissions in the active directory for an account?

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess, but it sounds like an issue with the trust levels. See if the info contained here helps:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648243.aspx
- http://www.csharp411.com/executing-code-in-partial-trust-environments/

Are you running it as an administrator on your box and a more limited account on the server?

If so, I would try running it at full trust on the server (if you can) to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: This was the problem in my case. It can be tested by setting the trust level in `web.config` and running on your local computer (`<system.web><trust level="Medium"/></system.web>`). This will most likely give the same result as when running on your server. NB. You can't set the web server to Full Trust using this method.