# What does error 110 per AuthzInitializeContextFromSid signify? "While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (110) occurred."

Tags: asp.net, c++, security, winapi, active-directory

My symptoms and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement stack trace are exactly the same as [While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814561/while-trying-to-retrieve-the-authorization-groups-an-error-5-occurred) except that I get an error 110 which [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) explain as ERROR_OPEN_FAILED: The system cannot open the device or file specified.

In my situation, this functionality was working one day and stopped working the next day within an ASP.NET v4 application. I am using an AD service account that I've created in order to establish a connection to AD. The service account has admin privileges to a specific OU further down in the directory.

I've narrowed the exception down to a call made to the [AuthzInitializeContextFromSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) native function inside the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthZSet constructor. It is not clear to me why this fails and since user.GetGroups works for me (per the  answer given in the other SO link), I'll put my research on hold for now.

Does anyone else have any thoughts on what might be occurring?

Comment: What does C++ have to do with .NET issues?

Comment: @ildjarn, he is trying to retrieve authorization groups from an ASP.NET web app written in C#. The error is originating down in some C++ code (found with Reflector.)

Comment: It's a win32 function that is throwing the error. #include <azroles.h>

Comment: The majority of the functionality in .NET originates in native code written in C or C++, but that doesn't mean that any question involving .NET should be tagged C or C++. I think it's inappropriate and unrelated in this case.

Comment: I understand your concern; however, this is a case where .NET is not appropriately wrapping native functionality; after all, when do the .NET base class libraries throw exceptions containing only a Win32 error code? Furthermore, how is a .NET developer interested in learning more about Win32 supposed to learn more about the native surface of Windows without some support from seasoned veterans such as yourself? Please help a man out if you have some ideas. I'm flummoxed.

Comment: @Jason : I'm fluent in C++, but I don't know anything about your question. Point being, tagging a language implies that knowledge of said language would be helpful/required in order to contribute an answer, which is clearly not the case here. The `winapi` tag makes sense and is appropriate, the `c++` tag does not and is not.

Answer (score 2):

Error 5 usually means you are having an [ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED win32 error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That can happen if you're accessing a downlevel API that can only be queried with administrative rights or if the object you are accessing has ACLs that deny access from the process token your program is running at.

In simple words: try running your app elevated. If it works, you had insufficient access rights when running without elevation.

Comment: Actually, I was getting an Error 110. The weird thing is that most of the time it works. Only occasionally does it fail with a 110; when it does fail, a reboot fixes it. Also, not sure how running elevated in an asp.net app would work? Already running at full trust.

Comment: In my case this happens when two asp.net apps are running with the same app pool account and both making calls to  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.AuthZSet.  I think this has something to do with nt security where only a single connection to AD can be made from a windows device using the same account.