# Why might UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups() fail for one principal but not another?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am running the following code in an ASP.Net MVC website:

```
  using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, DOMAIN))
  using (var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, principal.Identity.Name))
  using (var groups = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups())
```

The code is used a custom RoleProvider and the variable "principal" is HttpContext.Current.User. DOMAIN is my local domain.

This code works fine when I log in to the site, but throws an exception on the last line if I log in as either of a couple of test users.

```
While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred.
```

The test users have fewer permissions on the domain but are users in active directory. I tried creating the PrincipalContext with an alternative constructor supplying my username and password but it didn't make any difference to the behaviour.

This happens both on my dev machine and also on a separate staging server so I don't think it has anything to do with local permissions. I also don't see how it can be related to the users' permissions as I would expect the active directory request to be made as the IIS App Pool user (impersonation is turned off) or perhaps the user specified in the PrincipalContext constructor.

Any suggestions as to what is going on gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not enough that they are users in Active Directory. The IIS App Pool user needs to be a member of the Windows Authorization Access Group to execute GetAuthorizationGroups.

Answered here: [While trying to retrieve the authorization groups, an error (5) occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814561/while-trying-to-retrieve-the-authorization-groups-an-error-5-occurred)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I follow - are you saying that everyone that might log in to the site needs to be a member of that group? I don't appear to be in that group and yet I can log in to the site (I am a domain admin though, not sure if that would help)

Comment: Everyone will have to be a member of that group unless you implement some sort of limited impersonation, yes. Also: Being the domain admin means you have full access to absolutely everything, yes :)

Comment: Hmm, I added the test user to Windows Authorization Access but they still can't log in. I'll try again tomorrow in case there's any caching affecting things.

Comment: @Dan - Since you are not using the users credentials to authenticate the lookup, you're using the worker processes domain credentials (NETWORK SERVICE and IIS APPPOOL users use DOMAIN\MACHINE$ user credentials if no credentials are used), so you must add the computer's account to the Windows Authorization Access Group.  As for why it works for some and not others, it depends on many factors, such as the rights assigned to groups and whether they are visible to the user doing the query.

Comment: @Erik thanks, this appears to be the missing piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @Dan - which part, the machine account or why some work and some don't? lol

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Mainly the machine account, it would be interesting to know why my login worked when it shouldn't have, but I can live with that :)